# Problema con If y Vector al Imprimir C++

Tags: c++

Buenos Dias, tengo el siguiente fragmento de un ejercicio, en el que estoy enviado a imprimir los datos de una persona que estan almacenados en un vector.

Inicialmente pido su cedula e inmediatamente me arroja sus datos. El problema viene cuando yo coloco una cedula que no exista o no este guardada en los vectores (para ello agrego un else, indicando que no se ha encontrado), sin embargo sale varias veces como puede apreciarse en la imagen.

```
case 3:

        do
        {
            system("cls");
            cout<<"< = = = = = F A B R I C A de F O R R O S para V E H I C U L O S = = = = = >";
            cout<<"\n\nOpcion 3: Consulta de Datos por Cedula";
            cout<<"\n\nIngrese el Numero de Cedula: ";
            cin>>consulta_cedula;

            for (i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++)
            {
                if (consulta_cedula == cedula[i])
                {
                    cout<<"\n\n------------------------------------";
                    cout<<"\n\nNombre del Trabajador: "<<nombre[i];
                    cout<<"\n\nCedula: "<<cedula[i];
                    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(0);
                    cout<<"\n\nForros Producidos en el Mes: "<<total_mensual[i];
                    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2);
                    cout<<"\n\nTotal a Pagar: Bs. "<<sueldo_mensual[i];
                    cout<<"\n\n------------------------------------";
                }else
                    cout<<"Cedula No Encontrada, Intente Nuevamente";
            }

            cout<<"\n\nDesea Consultar otro Trabajador? (S/N): ";
            cin>>resp;

        } while (resp == 's' || resp == 'S');

        cout<<"\n\n< < < - - - - - - - - - - - - - > > >";
        cout<<"\n\nDesea Volver al Menu? (S/N): ";
        cin>>resp;

        break;
```

Como EJEMPLO agregue 3 personas (3 datos almacenados en vectores).

IMAGEN 1: Correctamente me muestra la cedula valida con sus datos, pero sale 2 veces el mensaje de no encontrada, proveniente del "else".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

IMAGEN 2: Aqui coloco una cedula invalida y 3 veces me imprime el mensaje.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se logra solucionar esto? Veo que es debido al FOR pero entonces como mando a imprimir si no es con el for...

Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, lo que ocurre es que tu estas recorriendo todas las cédulas del vector, si el programa no la encuentra en la iteración 1 de n esta escribirá el mensaje, si no la encuentra en la siguiente escribirá el mensaje, y así sucesivamente.

Lo que puedes hacer es crear una bandera booleana y al terminar el ciclo verificar que la cedula se encuentre en el vector. De esta manera:

```
        bool flag = false;
        int pos = 0;
        for (i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++)
        {
            if (consulta_cedula == cedula[i]){
                flag = true;
                pos = i;
            }
        }
        if (flag){
            cout<<"\n\n------------------------------------";
            cout<<"\n\nNombre del Trabajador: "<<nombre[pos];
            cout<<"\n\nCedula: "<<cedula[pos];
            cout<<fixed<<setprecision(0);
            cout<<"\n\nForros Producidos en el Mes: "<<total_mensual[pos];
            cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2);
            cout<<"\n\nTotal a Pagar: Bs. "<<sueldo_mensual[pos];
            cout<<"\n\n------------------------------------";
        }else{
            cout<<"Cedula No Encontrada, Intente Nuevamente";
        }
```

Lo de la posición te la puedes ingeniar de otras formas, incluso puedes usar otra bandera para mejorar la eficiencia de tu algoritmo, no uses un for utiliza un while que como te mostré con la búsqueda, esta acabaría con el ciclo cuando encuentre la cédula, en caso de que exista en el vector.

```
bool flag_cedula = false;
int cont = 0;
//Mientras la cedula no haya sido encontrada y el contador sea menor que 
// n el ciclo continuara, una vez encontrada la cedula el ciclo termina inmediatamente
while(cont < n && !flag_cedula)
    if(consulta_cedula == cedula[i]){
        flag_cedula = true;
    }
    cont++;
}
```

Comment: Porque debe utilizarse el "pos = i;" ?

Comment: Necesitas la posición en donde se encuentran los datos relacionados a la cédula en dicha posición, era necesario guardarla, creo yo. Si no, no se como accederías a los datos como total_mensual asociados a esa cédula.